# Ubuntu 14.04 updates require reboot everyday

Tags: updates, ubuntu-14.04

I've Ubuntu 14.04LTS on my jobs desktop and every morning (EVERY morning really) I arrive and I have updates notifications. I update and everyday it requests me to reboot the pc. It's becoming so boring !

What happens is that I end up only rebooting on the friday or monday. Is the reboot so necessary to be asked everytime? What's the problem if I delay the reboot until one day of the week? (it's a bit boring to reopen all my required apps when I restart)

Comment: You should take a look at this answer, http://askubuntu.com/questions/8834/how-do-i-save-remember-last-used-window-position-and-size-for-applications

Comment: that's nice. But I really want to understand if it's normal to ask to reboot everyday, and why it asks..

Comment: No, rebooting every day is highly unusual. It asks because you might be in the middle of something, so that it wants to give you time to save your work.  When asked to reboot as a consequence of an update you **should** reboot, because some of your software may not work as expected in a partially updated configuration. To iagnose the problem, you should provide some message, from the /var/log directory, explaining why you are asked to reboot, and which packages have bene installed which require reboot. As it stands, trying to answer is just a shot in the dark.